# Grant ACL permission by URLs in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, permissions, zend-framework2, acl

I follow this tutorial: http://ivangospodinow.com/zend-framework-2-acl-setup-in-5-minutes-tutorial/
But, I want to grant permission by custom URLs, so I had some changes in my code.

In  **module.acl.roles.php**

```
return array(
    'guest'=> array(
        '/home.html',
        '/login.html',
        '/register.html'
    ),
    'admin'=> array(
        '/user/add.html',
        '/user/edit.html',
        '/user/list.html',
    ),
);
```

In **module.config.php**

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            '/home.html' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            '/user/add.html' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Regex',
                'options' => array(
                    'regex' => '/user/add.html',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\User',
                        'action' => 'add',
                        'format' => 'html',
                    ),
                    'spec' => '/user/add.%format%',
                ),
            ),
            ...
        ),
    ),
);
```

But I received this error: `Route with name "" not found`. Please give me some advices and solutions to grant permission by URLs

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you to look at https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize instead, namely route guard

Answer (score 0):

I really really recommend the BjyAuthorize module (https://packagist.org/packages/bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize).

But if you really want to do this by yourselft you need to add a listener to the `\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE`.

You can attach your listener with

```
$events->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, array($this, 'myOnRoute'), -1000);
```

and in your myOnRoute method you can handle the route

```
public function myOnRoute(MvcEvent $event) {
  $match      = $event->getRouteMatch();
  $routeName  = $match->getMatchedRouteName();
  // do stuff here (compare to config or whatever)
}
```